# HTML box model with margins

Tags: html, css

There's something in the box model of HTML block elements that I can't grasp.

Please have a look at the following jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5b7X2/1/

There is an outer and an inner `<div>`, and both of them have the same margin on their left, top, right and bottom. The outer `<div>`'s margin is transparent, so we see the white body around the coloured area. However, the inner `<div>`'s margin is only visible on the left and on the right. In my opinion, there should be a red bar of `50px` height above and below the orange area.

**Why am I wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vertical [margins collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) into each other (according to some fairly complex rules which you can find at the other end of that link), so the inner margin-top occupies the bottom half of the outer margin-top.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is about margin collapsing. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins has information about this.

Here is a workaround/solution of this.

```
<div id="outer">
    &nbsp;
    <div id="inner">
        Text
    </div>
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

​